# ASP.NET Core : creating form input for model property of type List

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have been searching online for an answer to this specific issue but I can't seem to find it.

I am currently creating a form using Razor pages and cannot find out how to create a form input that would be able to take multiple values for one item in the form. Below I will post a quick example of what I mean.

Current issues: when I add another input programmatically it will only add 2 maximum and will not send a value

Model:

```
public class FormInput 
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Razor Page:

```
public class FormPage : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty] public FormInput _Input { get; set; }
}
```

HTML Page:

```
<form>
    <ul class="Category-Container">
      <li>
        <input asp-for="_Input.Addresses" type="text" />
        <button type="button" onclick="this.AddCategory">
        Add New Address
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="_Input.Categories" type="text" />
        <button type="button" onclick="this.AddNewInput">
        Add New Category
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var categoryContainer = document.getElementById("Category-Container");

 function AddCategory() {

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.classList.add("w-100");
        input.name = "BusinessCategory";
        var inputCol = document.createElement("div");
        inputCol.classList.add("col-8");
        inputCol.appendChild(input);

        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.classList.add("btn");
        btn.classList.add("btn-primary");
        btn.innerText = "Add New Category";
        var btnCol = document.createElement("div");
        btnCol.classList.add("col");
        btnCol.appendChild(btn);

        var row = document.createElement("li");
        row.classList.add("row");
        var part1 = row.appendChild(inputCol);
        var part2 = part1.appendChild(btnCol);

        categoryContainer.appendChild(part2);
    }
```

There's a little disconnect in the javascript function but you can assume that the Button and the Input in the HTML example are inside of Columns also, i don't think that makes a big difference but please let me know if it would be one

Comment: Hi @Myles Frazier, could you please share your `this.AddNewInput` method?

Comment: Updated , Along with a quick description of the slight differences below

Comment: Hi @Myles Frazier, it seems you want to add Category to Address from your code? What is your two model relationship? Also, tag helper cannot pass complex model to backend ,so `asp-for="_Input.Addresses"` is not correct. If you want to post the data to backend, the input should be like :`asp-for="_Input.Addresses[0].PropertyName"`. Please share your model to us.

Comment: It DId thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag helper cannot pass complex model type data to backend, it only allows simple type. That is to say, you need set the model's property name in `asp-for`.

Then, if you want to get the list model, you need specific the list index like: `_Input.Categories[0].PropertyName`.

Not sure what is your whole view, here is a simple demo about how to pass list model to backend:

Model:

```
public class FormInput
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public string BusinessCategory { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <ul id="Category-Container">
        <li>
            <input asp-for="_Input.Categories[0].BusinessCategory" type="text" />
            <button type="button" onclick="AddCategory()">
                Add New Address
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="_Input.Addresses[0].Name" type="text" />
        <button type="button" onclick="this.AddNewInput">
            Add New Category
        </button>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    var count = 1;  //add count...
    var categoryContainer = document.getElementById("Category-Container");

    function AddCategory() {

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.classList.add("w-100");
   //change the name here.....
        input.name = "_Input.Categories["+count+"].BusinessCategory";
        var inputCol = document.createElement("div");
        inputCol.classList.add("col-8");
        inputCol.appendChild(input);

        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.classList.add("btn");
        btn.classList.add("btn-primary");
        btn.innerText = "Add New Category";
        var btnCol = document.createElement("div");
        btnCol.classList.add("col");
        btnCol.appendChild(btn);

        var row = document.createElement("li");
        row.classList.add("row");
        var part1 = row.appendChild(inputCol);
        part1.appendChild(btnCol); //change here...

        categoryContainer.appendChild(part1);  //change here...
        count++;  //add here ...
    }
</script>
}
```

Backend code:

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel
{
    [BindProperty] public FormInput _Input { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {

        return Page();
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {

    }
}
```